# Modules, Bound on size of freely generating set

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules

NB: R is commutative

Let M be a free module over a (non-trivial)commutative  ring R that is generated (not necessarily
freely) by a subset T ⊂ M of size m. Show that if S is a basis of M, then S is finite with
|S|$\leq$ m.

I have tried proving this directly using the definition of free basis functions can be uniquely extended to homomorphisms. But that has been fruitless.

So a new idea is to reduce to case of vector spaces by using the trick to Quotient by IM where I is a maximal ideal of R and consider this as an R/I module to get a vector space.

So we want to show if $R^m$ surjects (via f a R module hom) onto $R^n$ then $n\leq m$. I think that if we can construct from this a surjection from $(R/I)^m$ to $(R/I)^n$ as a R/I homomorphism then we are done.

so $q_n o f$ where where $q_n$ is the quotient map from $R^n to (R/I)^n$ gives us a surjection from $R^m to (R/I)^n$ but I'm not sure how to finish this argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another answer, this time assuming that $R$ is commutative.

**Theorem**.  Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring and let
$
  T:R^m\to R^n
  $
be a surjection.  Then $n\leq m$.

*Proof*.
Leting $\{e_1, \ldots ,  e_n\}$ be the canonical basis of $R^n$,  choose for each $i$,  a vector $u_i$ in $R^m$ such that
$T(u_i)=e_i$, and consider the linear transformation $S:R^n\to R^m$ defined on the canonical basis by
$$
  S(e_i)=u_i,\quad \forall i=1,\ldots ,n.
  $$
It is then evident that $T\circ S$ is the identity map on  $R^m$.

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$.  That is, $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with entries $a_{i, j}$ such that, for every
$(x_1,\ldots ,x_m)\in R^m$, one has that
$$
  T(x_1,\ldots ,x_m)=(y_1,\ldots ,y_n),
  $$
where
$$
  y_i=\sum_{j=1}^ma_{i,j}x_j, \quad \forall i=1,\ldots ,n.
  $$
Similarly let $B$ be the matrix for $S$.

From the fact that $T\circ S$ is the identity map on  $R^m$ we deduce that
$AB$ coincides with $I_n$,  the identity $n\times n$ matrix.

Choose any field $K$ and a unit preserving ring homomorphism $\varphi :R\to K$.  E.g., let $K$ be the quotient of $R$ by a
maximal ideal and let $\varphi $ the quotient map.

Denoting by $\varphi (A)$ the $n\times m$ matrix over $K$ obtained by applying $\varphi $ to each entry of $A$, and similarly for $\varphi (B)$, we
then have that
$$
  \varphi (A)\varphi (B) = \varphi (AB) = \varphi (I_n)=I_n,
  $$
from where we deduce that the rank of $\varphi (A)$ is $n$.

It is well known that the rank of an $n\times m$ matrix over a
field is at most $\min\{n, m\}$, so
$$
  n = \text{rank}(A) \leq  \min\{n, m\} \leq  m.
  $$
QED

Answer (score 0):

Without further assumptions on $R$ this is false.  There are examples of rings $R$ such that $$
R^n\simeq R^m
$$ for $n\neq m$.  In such a ring you may find two bases with different number of elements.

Comment: Could you give an example? We seem to prove the opposite in the course I'm taking. If you look at the bottom of page 72 here https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IB_L/groups_rings_and_modules.pdf
I think I'm misunderstanding something

We assume R is commutative in our couse

Comment: OK, so "commutativity" is the further assumption I was referring to!  This changes everything so I suggest you edit your question to make this explicit!

Comment: Alright, so now all you have to do is show that the last map you mentioned in your post vanishes on $I^n$, so it factors thru $(R/I)^m$.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by factors